# SOSL Offset Changes Order for Knowledge

Tags: apex, knowledge, sosl

I am Running into something that appears to be a bug in how Salesforce SOSL queries work with knowledge.

Consider this Snippet of code:

```
String searchquery = 'FIND \'SEARCH TERM\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Article__kav(Title, Summary, UrlName, LastPublishedDate, LastModifiedById WHERE PublishStatus =\'Online\' AND Language = \'en_US\'' + 
                     'AND Not_Searchable__c = false OFFSET 0) WITH DATA CATEGORY DataCat__c BELOW DataKitten__c ';
System.debug(search.query(searchquery));
```

Then this Snippet of code:

```
String searchquery = 'FIND \'SEARCH TERM\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Article__kav(Title, Summary, UrlName, LastPublishedDate, LastModifiedById WHERE PublishStatus =\'Online\' AND Language = \'en_US\'' + 
                     'AND Not_Searchable__c = false) WITH DATA CATEGORY DataCat__c BELOW DataKitten__c ';
System.debug(search.query(searchquery));
```

Now the only difference between the two queries is `OFFSET 0`, yet I am getting a completely different order. The relevance of the search seems to be completely disregarded the second I add `OFFSET` to the query.

Now what's even stranger is doing the query in the developer console:

Without Offset:

```
FIND {SEARCH TERM} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Article__kav(Title, Summary, UrlName, LastPublishedDate, LastModifiedById WHERE PublishStatus ='Online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND Not_Searchable__c = false) WITH DATA CATEGORY DataCat__c BELOW DataKitten__c
```

With Offset:

```
FIND {SEARCH TERM} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Article__kav(Title, Summary, UrlName, LastPublishedDate, LastModifiedById WHERE PublishStatus ='Online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND Not_Searchable__c = false OFFSET 0) WITH DATA CATEGORY DataCat__c BELOW DataKitten__c
```

The developer console showing the same order with and without the offset. Anyone have any idea what is happening on this?

**UPDATE**

It appears to be adding an Order By ID when Offset is included.. but that still does not explain why this is happening.

To further clarify the SOSL_EXECUTE_BEGIN in debug log does not show the `Order By ID` when it is executing the SOSL search. It's just returning the results in such a way.

Comment: Did you try to define any specific order?

Comment: @Oleksiy Well the order I need is relevance is there any way to specify to Order By using that?  From what I gathered reading the documentation if you want that you simply don't put in an Order By.

Comment: What's the purpose of using offset, here?

Comment: @sfdcfox we were using it for pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after logging a case with Salesforce. I got a response back from their R&D team, that it is indeed a bug. They have no idea how long before a fix will be implemented.

Here is the [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000f42NQAQ) created for it.